# NodeJS child_process, keep track of sub-processes started by child_process

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

Using NodeJS child_process spawn method, how can I keep track of sub processes spawned by the new child process? specifically the `close` event.

here's an example:
I `spawn()` a process, which happen to close itself immediately after starting it's own detached subprocess which I need to keep track of.
in the above example, the "close" event is immediately invoked, however the new spawn subprocesses are no longer tracked.

I tried passing a couple of options to the `spawn()` method, but I haven't found a way to tell when all the subprocesses have actually closed.

So how can I keep track of a process' spawned subprocesses? or at least get notified when all are closed.

Comment: Do you have control of how `spawn`ed  process is creating the subprocesses? Otherwise it's probably in the realm of OS specific introspection.

Comment: @Matt I have no control of the `spawn`ed process, in terms of code. basically this sub-process behavior is common for Steam games executables, which I'm launching/managing externally with a multiplayer-game-launcher (NukemNet)

Comment: Steam might even add another level of indirection here if steam uses its own IPC to launch the games, it tends to keep the one steam client as the parent of all processes being launched.

Comment: So probably need to look outside your process. On Windows could set up a WMI consumer filtered to process events. On Linux BPF is capable of attaching a probe to process creation and exit.  Then filter down to the processes you want, or the things steam does.